# How to have different columns headers in ssrs matrix with each of row groups.

Tags: reporting-services

I have a ssrs matrix report, there I have in row level group by [department] ,[group name], [function name] in columns level showing [user name]. I want to appear [user name] according to the [department] in the row. when certain department finish. I need to show next set of user names in column.

Please let me know if this one can go with this arrangement.

Comment: It certainly sounds possible but it would be very helpful if you could include images of what you have at the moment, and what the desired outcome would be